# Python Library Issue - import tflite-support.task on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python

I’m trying to import tflite-support.task on Raspberry Pi 4. However, I’m getting:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support.task'
Python version is 3.11.2 and tflite-support is 0.1.0a1.

I did some research and found that 0.1.0a1 version doesn’t include task library but the requirement for the object detection model in the GitHub repository 3 is tflite-support>=0.4.2.

When I try to install the dependency via pip:
python -m pip install --upgrade tflite-support==0.4.4,

the output is:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-support==0.4.4 (from versions: 0.1.0a0.dev3, 0.1.0a0.dev4, 0.1.0a0.dev5, 0.1.0a0, 0.1.0a1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-support==0.4.4

I’m kind of confused. Any idea of fixing the problem?

python -m pip install --upgrade tflite-support==0.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link and download the `Source code (zip)` of TFLite Support 0.4.4

https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/releases/tag/v0.4.4

Navigate to tensorflow_lite_support/tools/pip_package and install the package manually using pip through there using the command `pip install ./`

Answer (score 0):

According to `tflite_support` project here, https://pypi.org/project/tflite-support/ the library supports `python-3.7` and `python-3.8`, so you need to downgrade python to either of the above-mentioned versions.
And for `task`, `tflite_support==0.1.0` does not have the task module. You need a version of 0.4 and above. The latest version is `tflite-support==0.4.4`.
You need to install with `python-3.8`:

```
pip install tflite-support
```

This is the output from running with `python-3.8` on my machine:

```
import tflite_support.task
print(tflite_support.task.__doc__)
```

Output:

```
The TensorFlow Lite Task Library.

TensorFlow Lite Task Library contains a set of powerful and easy-to-use
task-specific libraries for app developers to create ML experiences with
TensorFlow Lite. It provides optimized out-of-box model interfaces for popular
machine learning tasks, such as image and text classification. The model
interfaces are specifically designed for each task to achieve the best
performance and usability.

Read more in the [Task Library Guide](
https://tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/overview).
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and confirmed that my version of python is 3.11.
It's the default python in my 64 bit Raspberry pi OS version 12.4.

Downloading tflite 0.4.4 and building it did not work for me.

So I tried installing python 3.8 and creating a virtual environment which overall worked.

First I found that I needed to install ssl-dev in order for the python build to have it

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Then build and install python3.8:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.18/Python-3.8.18.tgz
tar zxf Python-3.8.18.tgz
cd Python-3.8.18/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Create virtual environment:

```
python3.7 -m venv "my_env_name"
```

Source into the venv

```
source ./my_env_name/bin/activate
```

install tflite

```
pip install tflite-runtime
pip install tflite-support
```